# How can I convert a datatable to an array of binary? I need to exchange data from a .NET Core API to .NET framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

From my research, I found that the way that the .NET framework converts data is different from the what that .NET Core serializes to binary, so when I try to convert again do a datatable there is some differences between the data that I exchange from the API to my windows form application.

Here is my code in C#:

```
public byte[] GetDataTable(string sqlStr, string connectionString)
{
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
        DataTable dataTable = CriaDataTable(sqlStr,connectionString);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, dataTable);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
}
```

and here is in VB.NET:

```
Public Function ApiGetDataTable(sqlStr As String, connectionString As String) As DataTable
    Dim url As String = $"{_baseUrl}GetDataTable?sqlStr={Uri.EscapeDataString(sqlStr)}&connectionString={Uri.EscapeDataString(connectionString)}"

    Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)
    request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/octet-stream")

    Dim response = _httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

    Dim content As Byte() = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataTable))

    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream(content)
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream), DataTable)
        Return dataTable
    End Using

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

I am expecting that when I convert again to a datatable the data be equals to the data that was sent by the API.

Comment: `DataTable` is a built-in type, over which you have no control, and which is likely to include a ton of stuff you don't need when serializing.  Overall I'd call it a poor choice for a data *exchange* format.  Why not exchange a list of custom objects instead?  That way you have complete control over the structure, how it's serialized and de-serialized, and what's sent over the wire.

Comment: You're not using "array of binary" anywhere. You're serializing to XML, putting that into a MemoryStream, then returning the array of bytes that produces. That itself is not the best way to convert XML to an array of bytes; it's also unnecessary; just serialize to XML and return it (as a string). Then deserialize from XML (string) to a DataTable.  As @David notes, it would likely be more efficient to use custom types, but serializing DataTables as XML was one of the use cases Microsoft had back in the day.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to assume Core & Framework differ in terms of how they deal with serialization. But binary serialization is not recommended because it's not cross-platform and can lead to security and versioning issues.

I would serialize it as JSON:

```
public string GetDataTable(string sqlStr, string connectionString)
{
    DataTable dataTable = CriaDataTable(sqlStr,connectionString);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
}
```

Then if you still require bytes if sending over a network..

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

//back to string
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score -3):

To convert a DataTable to an array of bytes (binary data), you can use the `BinaryFormatter` class available in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` namespace. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static byte[] DataTableToByteArray(DataTable dataTable)
{
   //Serialize the DataTable to a MemoryStream
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
       BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
       formatter.Serialize(stream, dataTable);

        //Convert the MemoryStream to a byte array
         return stream.ToArray();
      }
}
```

In this example, the `DataTableToByteArray` method takes a DataTable as input and returns a byte array. It uses the `BinaryFormatter` to serialize the DataTable into a MemoryStream, and then converts the MemoryStream to a byte array using the `ToArray()` method.

You can call this method to convert your DataTable into a byte array before exchanging it between your .NET Core API and .NET Framework application. On the receiving side, you can deserialize the byte array back to a DataTable using the BinaryFormatter.

Note that the BinaryFormatter class is available in both .NET Core and .NET Framework, so you can use it for serialization and deserialization in both environments.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that ChatGPT answers are [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) here on the site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As should be obvious by now, your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!
 Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.